# How do I make my rectangle disappear in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new and using Wix for my site. I have this HTML code for my rectangle and I want to make it disappear after 30 seconds.

What do I add? Also, what can I take out and still keep the blue rectangle?

Thank you so much for the help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p.one
    {
      width: 100px; height: 100px;
      background-color: #0000ff
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <p class="one">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do :

`setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery('.one').hide();
},30000);`